# TypeError: _this[("render" + data.type)] is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syncfusion

[image]

This is an error I'm getting in the console. I don't know why I'm getting this moreover I have written the code according to the documentation of `Syncfusion` library.

Below is the code I have written:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SparklineComponent, Inject, SparklineTooltip } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react- 
charts';

const Sparkline = ({ id, height, width, color, currentColor, data, type }) => {
    return (
       <SparklineComponent
          id={id}
          height={height}
          width={width}
          lineWidth={1}
          valueType="Numeric"
          fill={color}
          border={{ color: currentColor, width: 2 }}
          dataSource={data}
          xName="x"
          yName="y"
          type={type}
          tooltipSettings={{
              visible: true,
              format: '${x} : data ${y}', //Getting error in this line//
              trackLineSettings: {
                  visible: true
              }
          }}
      >
          <Inject services={[ SparklineTooltip ]} />
      </SparklineComponent>
  );
};

 export default Sparkline;
```

Below is the screenshot of the documentation and the link to it too.

[image: Documentation ScreenShot]

[Link to Syncfusion Documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/sparkline/user-interaction/)

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to `type` value of `SparklineComponent` being incorrect. Following are the available types. `type` value is Case Sensitive.

[image]